# Hey everyone I have problem in sorting queryset in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

So, I am learning Django and trying to make a site similar to AirBNB.
I have models called lisitngs that has latitude and longitude stored in CharField. My model is as follows:

```
class Listing(models.Model):

    class BathRoomType(models.TextChoices):
        ATTACHED = 'Attached Bathroom'
        COMMON   = 'Shared Bathroom'
    
    class RoomVentType(models.TextChoices):
        AC      = 'Air Conditioner'
        NO_AC   = 'No Air Conditioner'

    class LisitngType(models.TextChoices):
        ROOM        = 'Room'
        APARTEMENT  = 'Apartement'
        HOUSE       = 'Full House'
    
    user                = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title               = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city                = models.ForeignKey(RoomLocation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exact_address       = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lat                 = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False, null=False, default="0")
    lng                 = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False, null=False, default="0")
    description         = models.TextField()
    price               = models.IntegerField()
    listing_type        = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LisitngType.choices, default=LisitngType.ROOM)
    kitchen_available   = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    kitchen_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    bedrooms            = models.IntegerField()
    max_acomodation     = models.IntegerField()
    bathroom_type       = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=BathRoomType.choices, default=BathRoomType.ATTACHED)
    no_bathrooms        = models.IntegerField()
    room_type           = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=RoomVentType.choices, default=RoomVentType.AC)
    main_photo          = models.ImageField(upload_to='room_images', default='default_room.jpg')
    photo_1             = models.ImageField(upload_to='room_images', default='default_room.jpg')
    photo_2             = models.ImageField(upload_to='room_images', default='default_room.jpg')
    photo_3             = models.ImageField(upload_to='room_images', default='default_room.jpg')
    is_published        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_created        = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    slug                = AutoSlugField(populate_from=['title', 'listing_type', 'bathroom_type', 'room_type'])
    rating              = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    approved            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total_bookings      = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In my homepage what I want to do is show the listings which are nearby me.
For that I have a function named as near_places. This near_place function takes latitude and longitude after querying through the model Listing and returns the distance between the listing and current user accessing the homepage:

```
import geocoder
from haversine import haversine

def near_places(dest_lat, dest_lng):
    g = geocoder.ip('me')
    origin = tuple(g.latlng)

    destination = (dest_lat, dest_lng)

    distance    = haversine(origin, destination)

    return distance
```

My homepage function in views.py is as follows:

```
def home(request):

    objects = Listing.objects.filter(is_published=True, approved=True)
    
    for object in objects:
        lat, lng = float(object.lat), float(object.lng)
        object.distance = near_places(lat, lng)


    return render(request, 'listings/home.html')
```

As you can see I have looped through the query set and for each data I have calculated the distance and appended in the queryset as distance. Now, I would like to only get 10 items that has lowest distance. How, can I do so.

I have tried to user object = objects.order_by('-distance')[:10] but it gives me error as

```
FieldError at /
Cannot resolve keyword 'distance' into field. Choices are: The_room_booked, approved, bathroom_type, bedrooms, city, city_id, date_created, description, exact_address, id, is_published, kitchen_available, kitchen_description, lat, listing_type, lng, main_photo, max_acomodation, no_bathrooms, photo_1, photo_2, photo_3, price, rating, reviewsandrating, room_type, slug, title, total_bookings, user, user_id
```

Any way that I can solve it?
Also it takes quite a time to calculate current distance using near_places() function as above. Any suggestions will be helpful.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, because your model doesn't have a `distance` field and there is no such DB column as well.

What you can do is either

1. add such field to your model - I don't recommend with your current logic as you will iterate over every instance and send sql request to update every row.
2. get your queryest, convert it to a list of dicts and then iterate over your list of dicts with your function adding the `distance` key to it. Then you can sort the list by the python sort function and pass it to the template.

Like:

```
objects = Listing.objects.filter(is_published=True, approved=True).values('lat', 'lng') # add fields that you need
for obj in objects:
    obj['distance'] = near_places(obj['lat'], obj['lng'])

my_sorted_list = sorted(objects, key=lambda k: k['distance'])
```

Pass `my_sorted_list` to your template. You can add `reverse=True` arg to `sorted` function if you want another direction sorting.

Comment: Thank you it worked but it doesn't allows me to render the image now as the main_photo will contain only the picture name and I can't get url using {{posts.main_photo.url}}. Any ideas to solving it?

Comment: Add it to values `values('lat', 'lng', 'main_photo__url')` and it will be available in that dict. you can add any field you need in template there.

Comment: @SulabhGhimire If it fixes your issue could you mark my answer as solution?

Comment: I tired using 'main_photo__url' in values but I have received an error that says FieldError at / Cannot resolve keyword 'url' into field. Join on 'main_photo' not permitted.